# Phone number verification via OTP using firebase and flutter

Tags: firebase, mobile, flutter, firebase-authentication

I don't want to authenticate the user via their phone number that I have already done by using their email id and password. I just want to confirm that they are entering a valid phone number by sending them an OTP and verifying it. All the solutions that I have looked up go on to straight up authenticate the user. I am using firestore as my database.

Comment: I had the same issue. Ended up using Facebook Account Kit

Answer (score 2):

Firebase allows you to link multiple authentication methods. You can find more details at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

So, once the user is authenticated with email/password, initiate phone number authentication. When you get `AuthCredential` link it to current firebase user as mentioned in above link.

Other solutions would be to use external SMS gateway like **twilio** and doing phone number verification on your own. Which isn't required for your use case. In case you still want to try this, there is a free SMS gateway (which uses your own mobile number to send SMS) at https://www.sg.yagnyam.in/.

Comment: Otherway would be doing verification on your own like mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Actually I just want to verify the number during the updation of mobile number section.. so you see if the user keeps on updating its number then won't it be messy to link so many numbers to a single account

Comment: If you don't want to use firebase. Send a SMS using any SMS gateway like Twilo and verify. But if you want head start use https://www.sg.yagnyam.in/. You can contact me using contact on that site if you need more details about using it.